# Simple display method

Tags: axapta, x++

I have 2 tables:

```
Table: country1 - fields: CountryId ,CountryName 
Table: City1    - fields: CityId, CityName, CountryId
```

There is a relation between 2 tables through the `CountryId`, each city has a `Country id` and there is a form with single datasource `City1`
and grid with fields `CityId,CityName, CountryId`
I need to display a `CountryName` instead of `CountryId` in the grid
I created a new method in `design-designs-grid-methods-new` methods

```
display CountryName method1(City1 cit)
{
    Country1 c1;
    select CountryName from c1
        where c1.CountryId == cit.CountryId;
    return c1.CountryName;
}
```

but when form open the id still shows as a id not a `CountryName`

Answer (score 1):

If possible, strive to add [display methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa595058.aspx) to the table where it belongs, in this case `City1`:

```
display CountryName contryName()
{
    return (select firstOnly CountryName from Country1 
                where Country1.CountryId == this.CountryId).CountryName;
}
```

Display methods on tables takes no arguments, use `this` keyword instead.
To avoid redundant variables you *may* use an inline [select expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677512.aspx) as show here.
After dragging the display method from the table to the form container control, remember to set the `Datasource` attribute on the resulting control.

Answer (score -1):

Move your display method to dataSource of the form. Also remove countryid field from grid and drag display method as grid field. 
Recommended approach is adding the display method in table City1. For that need to modify your existing display method to use table buffer as this.

Comment: Please don't suggest creating display methods on the form without context, they are not reusable and have terrible performance.